# How to enable the "late" version package in R (version higher into the package)- function/package "tracks"?

Tags: r, plot, graph, google-genomics, bigdata

I tried to use the function/package "tracks", in R, but the version is not compatible. First, I thought that this function be of package "ggbio", but I installed this and don't running.

I will use this function/package for merge two graphs, will be in same scale y. (A graph on top of the other, in same scale y)

For enable, I tried

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("tracks", type = "source")

install.packages("tracks", type="source", repos=NULL)
```

No way it worked. The version R in my computer is 3.3.0 (in Windows) and 3.2.3 (in Linux- Ubuntu).

Anyone ever used this function / package, and can help me?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what does it do and what did you expect it to do?

Comment: you seem indeed to speak of function `tracks` from `ggbio` package. Have you installed `ggbio` package ? have you loaded it (with `library`)? if so, you should be able to use function `tracks` (`source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R"); biocLite("ggbio") ; library("ggbio") ; ?tracks`)

Comment: I hope that the function/package tracks run. But same after this steps, appear the error when I use function "stracks". Because I have 2 plots, and I want one graphs on top of the other, in same scale "y", but this do not happy. And the error that appear is package non-install. 
I was clear? or was too confusing? (I am sorry)

Comment: you seem to confuse `package` and `function`. You need to install `ggbio` and, if you already installed it, you need to load it with `library` before you can use the functions included in the package. What does R tell you when you do `library(ggbio)` ?

Comment: @cath I think that the error is in installation of ggbio. Because when I used `library(ggbio)`apper the following error: `there is no package called 'ggbio'`. And I try to install but don't do. When install appear following errors: `installation of package 'ggbio' had non-zero exit status.` What can that be? Thank you and I am sorry.

Comment: error happens when you do `source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R"); biocLite("ggbio")` on your windows `R3.3.0` version ?